# IIS Password Protection for PHP

Tags: php, iis, password, iis-7.5, windows-7

How do i create a password protection for my whole iis website, which uses php for most of its sites? I put a web.config in the root folder, but that seemed to do nothing.  What i want is a way to protect my entire site so that the only way to see any web page is to login similar to using .htaccess for apache. Except i probably want it to be able to use windows login. Here was the web.config i used.

```
 <configuration>
    <system.web>
       <authentication mode="Windows" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install windows/basic authentication and then disable anonymous authentication in IIS administration console.

Comment: It took a little while to figure out what you meant, but i eventually got it to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do equivalence of htaccess using a htpasswd or alike, but you can create windows accounts and right click your webroot, then in security tab limit access to a specific user (or groups of users).

Comment: What i meant by the htaccess thing was just that i wanted it to popup asking for a password, instead of me having to use php to code it.  And i was trying what you said, but i accidentally denied ComputerName\Users which apparently includes the Administrator as well. Oops. Gotta find a way to reset that.

Comment: I fixed the permission accident, but it is still giving me a 500 error instead of asking for a user name and password. Is there a way i can get it to ask?  I want it to be accessible to anywhere on the outside, but only people who are authenticated can view the site.